# Добавленный через styles.css баннер не отображается на рабочем сервере. Вкладка Network браузера (Opera, Chrome) показывает ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER

Tags: css, django, amazon-web-services

Бэкенд на django, хост - heroku, хранилище файлов AWS S3, расширение баннера .png, добавлен не через тег static, а из файла styles.min.css:

```
    ...}.blockquote{background-image:url("../images/banner.png");...
```

Во вкладке Network браузера Opera отображается с ошибкой (failed)net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCK, адблок выключен, а баннер не отображается в Safari Iphone и Chrome на андроид-смартфоне.
Пути css и images для сравнения:

```
    "app/css/styles.min.css"
    "app/images/banner.png"
```

Comment: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCK и «адблок выключен» не очень сочетаются в одном предложении. Кто-то врёт.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять название файла `banner.png` (Например: `img.png`, `picture.png`, `background.png`, и т. д.). Просто Adblock и другие браузеры решают, что файл `banner.png` является рекламой и блокируют его.

Comment: @Никита Благодарю, это сработало. Странный примитивный способ... Переименовать вредоносный баннер этот метод защиты никому из желающих и умеющих не помешает, а вот я попался.